# Communication Android with Arduino Buffer incomplete

Tags: java, android, arduino, buffer

i'm trying to send some data from Arduino to Android device, i saw some examples but the communication is from Android to Arduino but i want to receive some data example:

```
Serial.write("holamundo");
```

via OTG, the connection is sucessful but i have some problem with this code.

```
  @Override
public void run() {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
    try{
        while (true) {
            request.queue(buffer, 100);
            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) {
                byte [] bytearray = buffer.array();
                mgsfinal = new String(bytearray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(mgsfinal.length()>0){
                            serialText.setText("Bytes: " +mgsfinal); // for UTF-8 encoding);

                        }

                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        etemp = e;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                serialText.setText("Bytes: " +etemp.getCause().toString()); // for UTF-8 encoding);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Im receiving in first iteration "hol", then i receive "hola", then hol. but never the complete string.

I don't know what's wrong. please help. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After severals day of investigation i found the solution.

Hope this helps.

Set this make the communications works and accept data.

```
  usbDeviceConnection = connection;
  usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true);

  usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x22, 0x1, 0, null, 0, 0);



// queue a request on the interrupt endpoint
            request.queue(buffer, buffer.capacity());
            // wait for status event
            if(usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request)
            {
                // there is no way to know how many bytes are coming, so simply forward the non-null values

                for(int i = 0; i < buffer.capacity() && buffer.get(i) != 0 ; i++)
                {
                    // transform ascii (0-255) to its character equivalent and append
                    dataByte = Character.toString((char) buffer.get(i));
                    data +=dataByte;
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Was not able to read from USB device, ending listening thread ----> "+ data);


                }
            }
```

Now contat the String variable data